# Mixed Platforms in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a WPF application and configure as 'Mixed Platforms'. My only options in the configuration manager are 'Any CUP', 'x86', and 'x64'.

How do I add 'Mixed Platforms' to the configuration manager? Or do WPF applications not support Mixed Platforms?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing 'Any CPU' with mixed platforms.

It's not a platform you can select because it's an indication of solution wide inconsistency.

One project uses 'Any CPU' while another only has 'x86' for example.

Comment: I have an example WPF application which is configured with mixed platforms (is that right?). It references a .dll, compiles, and runs fine. 

Now I want to make my own sample WPF application with that same dll. The program can't reference the .dll when configured in anyCUP, or in x86, or in x64.

It worked in the example which was mixed platforms, it doesn't work with my test application with any of the other 3. Am I barking up the wrong tree by thinking it's a configuration thing?

Comment: Depends. Some projects may require x86 (for example if they bundle a 32-bit native code DLL) and changing that to AnyCPU may break it.

In any case you normally don't *want* mixed platform. You need to figure out how far you can stretch it. In an ideal world filled with flowers and honey all applications would target 'Any CPU'. However since we live in a gray industrial landscape filled with "make it work"-solutions you may be required to target 'x86'. If the entry-point application is 'x86' or "prefer x86" is enabled then 'Any CPU' should defer to that.